# An if statement to check within try statement in Python, need the code to execute in case an exception is raised as well

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, try-catch

I'm a bit stumped here. Here's a piece of Python code:

```
try:
    if parse[index+1][0] != "5":
        individual_services+=[individual_services_cur]
        individual_services_cur=[]
except IndexError:
    warning("Reached end of file. No next element")
    individual_services+=[individual_services_cur]
    individual_services_cur=[]
```

Basically I want these two actions (addition of `individual_services_cur` list to `individual_services` list and clearing of `individual_services_cur` list) to take place either if the next element in `parse` is not "5" or if it doesn't exist (basically it is the end of file).

I am wondering if there is a more elegant (maybe even, as they say, "pythonic") way to write this code, for example, without the need to write these two actions twice. I couldn't think of any good solution with `finally` or `else` statements, and it seems that I cannot get rid of `try` statement because once the end of file is reached, the `IndexError` exception is inevitably raised.

Comment: It appears the the two things you want to happen don't depend on the `if parse[index+1][0] != "5"` at all -- so just leave it out (and the `try/except`) and perform the two of them.

Comment: @martineau: that's not true, if the element is say "4" then the code isn't run

Comment: @Highstaker does any of the answer below helped you? If yes, select one as your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another idea:

```
update_i_s = True

try:
    update_i_s= parse[index+1][0] != "5"
except IndexError:
    warning("Reached end of file. No next element")
finally:
    if update_i_s:
        individual_services.append([individual_services_cur]) if flag
        individual_services_cur=[]
```

`flag=True` is only needed for the case that there is only one line in the file, and only needs to be set once at the beginning (so don't go putting it inside any loops).

---

EDIT:

By the way, if there is a possibility the `finally` block could fail, you might want to do something like this:

```
try:
    try:
        update_i_s= parse[index+1][0] != "5"
    except IndexError:
        warning("Reached end of file. No next element")
    finally:
        if update_i_s:
            individual_services.append([individual_services_cur]) if flag
            individual_services_cur=[]
except Exception:
    warning("failed to update individual_services")
    raise
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an intermediate variable to perform the checks you need.

```
try:
    value_to_check = parse[index+1][0]

except IndexError:
    warning("Reached end of file. No next element")
    value_to_check = None
finally:
    if value_to_check != "5":
        individual_services+=[individual_services_cur]
        individual_services_cur=[]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could assign a variable in both cases and then check it once.

```
badstuff = False
try:
    if parse[index+1][0] != "5":
        badstuff = True
except IndexError:
    warning("Reached end of file. No next element")
    badstuff = True

if badstuff:
    individual_services+=[individual_services_cur]
    individual_services_cur=[]
```

If it suits you, you could put the `if badstuff:` in a `finally` block, depending on what the rest of your code is doing.

Alternatively, put the `individual_services` stuff in a function, and call it in both places.

Comment: I thought about using a separate variable like this, but it felt like a not very "pythonic" way of doing it. Maybe I shouldn't care much about it though...

Comment: Not worrying too much about it being pythonic is very pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
last = len(parse) - 1

if index == last or parse[index + 1][0] != "5":
    individual_services.append(individual_services_cur)
    individual_services_cur = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Or thinking outside the box a bit:

```
if index + 1 not in (index for index, value in enumerate(parse) if value[0] == '5'):
    individual_services+=[individual_services_cur]
    individual_services_cur=[]
```

Where `(index for index, value in enumerate(parse) if value[0] == '5')` is a generator that yields the line number of each line that has a '5' as the first character. It is equivalent to this:

```
def has_5s(p):
    '''Yield line numbers that begin with a 5'''
    for index, line in enumerate(p):
        yield index if line[0] == '5'

if index + 1 not in has_5s(parse):
    individual_services+=[individual_services_cur]
    individual_services_cur=[]
```

You are simply checking to see if the following line number (`line + 1`) is one of these line numbers yielded by the generator. Since `enumerate` and the generator itself are lazy this should be very fast.